# How is the value of row column is estimated in EXPLAIN statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql, explain

I have the following setup:

```
create table Test(id integer, itemID integer, title varchar(100) ,PRIMARY KEY (id, itemID));
insert into Test(id, itemID, title) values(1,678, "Hello");
insert into Test(id, itemID, title) values(1,679, "how");
insert into Test(id, itemID, title) values(1,680, "are");
insert into Test(id, itemID, title) values(2,692, "you");
insert into Test(id, itemID, title) values(2,693, "iam");
```

And I'm running this query:

```
Explain select * from Test where id IN (1,2,3) AND itemID IN (679,692);
```

In [v8.0.12](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/24) I'm getting 6 in the *Rows* column. Is it a bug? Since there are only 5 rows.

In [v8.0.21](https://paiza.io/projects/u8I7CrHK-fo4ormTsSmXPw?language=mysql) I'm getting 5.

Comment: Please consider including _everything_ that's needed to answer your question in the question itself. Once the link you have included goes stale, your question as is won't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

That actually depends on which version of mysql you use

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/23

```
mysql 8 estimates 6 rows
and mysql 5.7 and 5.6 think it must examine 5 rows
```

The definition of rows is

> Estimate of rows to be examined

see  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-output-columns

This means:

That it only gives the estimated number of rows, that MySQL **believes** it must examine from the examined table, to execute the query.

This is as the description already  tells you only an estimated number.

if you have a high row count then there is some room for optimization. As lower rows count means faster queries

Comment: Can one know the source code for how it estimates?

Comment: In v8.0.21 returns 5 too

Comment: that depends not only on source code version version but also on operating system and compiler.

Comment: Can one see what are the rows to be examined?

Comment: Even approximation , how it returns 6 since there is only 5 rows.

Comment: What is the optimum row count?

Comment: id didn't look in the github spurce, but iam guessing that is only a rounding error as is the 54 that you got, so the operating system and compiler, could be mxed in besides the code. As we try to explain, when you see there a **big** difference betwenn estimated rows and whyt you expect, you have some more programming to do and have to optimize the query. 1 or 2 difference aren't a problem 200000 are